# highcharts series data[] not populating/displayed

Tags: json, highcharts

I am facing problem in displaying a Basic column highchart. my json looks line below:

```
[
{
    "name":"Target Assigned",
    "data":["100000","100000","100000","100000","100000","100000","100000"]
},

{
    "name":"Target achieved",
    "data":["75000","80000","80000","75000","85000","90000","65000"]
}
]
```

i want the "data" to be set to series data , for this i wrote below code but it doesn't display anything,

```
<script>$(document).ready( function () {

var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 70
        },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Target Tracker'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Database'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        tickInterval: 5,
        title: {
            text: 'Rupees (Lakhs)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} Lakh</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{name:'' , data: []},{name:'' , data: []}]
}

    $.getJSON("tracktarget.json", function(json) {
        //alert(1);
       // var jp=JSON.parse(json);

        options.series[0].name= json[0].name;
        options.series[0].data= [JSON.parse(json[0].data[0])];
        options.series[1].name= json[1].name;
        options.series[1].data= [JSON.parse(json[1].data[0])];

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


});
});
</script>
```

this code is setting the "name:" of the series element to the "name" value in my json, but not setting the data array values.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you please share a JS Fiddle of this code? It will be much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect your console for errors.  In your case you are getting:

```
Uncaught Highcharts error #19: www.highcharts.com/errors/19
```

> Too many ticks
>
> This error happens when you try to apply too many ticks to an axis,
>   specifically when you add more ticks than the axis pixel length. In
>   practice, it doesn't make sense to add ticks so densely that they
>   can't be distinguished from each other. One cause of the error may be
>   that you set a tickInterval that is too small for the data value
>   range. In general, tickPixelInterval is a better option, as it will
>   handle this automatically. Another case is if you try to set
>   categories on a datetime axis, which will result in Highcharts trying
>   to add one tick on every millisecond since 1970.

Sure enough, you have set `tickInterval: 5`, which means draw a tick every 5 on a yaxis that'll go up over 100,000!

If you comment out that line your code works.  Although I'm very confused by this line:

```
options.series[0].data= [JSON.parse(json[0].data[0])];
```

This means you are only setting the series to the first datapoint. I would have assumed you wanted the whole data series.  **BUT** you have another problem:

```
"data":["100000","100000","100000","100000","100000","100000","100000"]
```

Those numbers are *strings* (this is why you have that strange `JSON.parse` to coerce them into a numbers).  Really you should fix your json to return an array numbers not strings.